# Error in converting multiple images to JPG

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I am trying to convert multiple images to JPG below is my code

```
                     onPressed: () async {
                      for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                        var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(
                            images[i].identifier);
                        print("path");
                        print(path);
                        final output = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                        var _image;
                        var destination = '${output.path}/test_image$index.jpg';
                        index = index + 1;

                        _image = File(destination)..writeAsBytesSync(img.encodeJpg(path));
                        GallerySaver.saveImage(_image.path, albumName: 'Image Resizer')
                            .then((bool success) {
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                              msg: "Image saved",
                              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                              timeInSecForIosWeb: 5,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16.0);
                        });
                      }
```

but I am getting below error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5UP2.png

Comment: You need to load an image by path and put it to method that format images.

Comment: I can not understand what you are trying to say can you check it through anydesk plz

Comment: what is img.encodeJpg() definition? It takes String and what it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image` plugin operate with `Image` class as input for formatting methods. You can create an instance of `Image` class by calling `decodeImage` method:

```dart
final imageFile = img.decodeImage(File(path).readAsBytesSync());
final encodedImage = img.encodePng(imageFile);
_image = File(destination)..writeAsBytesSync(encodedImage);
```

Comment: do you how to convert multiple images to pdf